# How to package dependencies with maven nbm plugin

Tags: maven, netbeans-platform

I have modified netbeans module jar that I want to package with my module. How do I do this ?

**Dependency in context**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-db-dataview</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${dbdataview}</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

**mvn nbm configuration**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <additionalArguments>${netbeans.run.params.ide}</additionalArguments>
                <netbeansInstallation>/home/venkat/netbeans-7.1.1/</netbeansInstallation>
                <keystore>keystore</keystore>
                <keystorealias>ezondaice</keystorealias>
                <keystorepassword>ezondaice</keystorepassword>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Edit**

I have the following dependency as well. This one seems to get packaged with the nbm inside

`/netbeans/modules/ext/org.yaml/`. Not sure why the other dependency is not being packaged into nbm.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can't you just install the modified jar in your local repo and/or nexus? Possibly with a different version?

Comment: I did install it using `install:install-file` and this is allowing me to build the project with dependency included in the POM. I know I can use assembly plugin to package the jar. But, I am not quite sure this would be enough as I want to package the nbm with all its configuration so that netbeans can install it when the my plugin is installed.

For now, I am thinking I will just zip the db-dataview nbm and my plugin and distribute it. I can do this because I don't need the dependency for compilation but need it at runtime.